# GetType().ToString() Returns Unexpected Characters

Tags: c#, tostring, gettype

I'm fairly new to .Net and was looking at how a base object array would handle different types. I tend to use the GetType().ToString() combination in a switch to centralize my event handling in code and I encountered the following return values. I've looked for an answer here and elsewhere (including the C# spec) but can't find where this is directly addressed:

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Objectify
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object[] arrObjects = {"", 0, 0.0M, 'a', new Stack<string>(), new Queue<string>(), new Stack<int>(), new Queue<int>()};

            for (int i = 0; i < arrObjects.Length; i++ )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arrObjects[i].GetType().ToString());
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
System.String
System.Int32
System.Decimal
System.Char
System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[System.String]
System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[System.String]
System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[System.Int32]
```

The "`1" part of lines 5 - 8 are unexpected from my perspective.

a) Can someone explain what is going on here? 
b) Is there some way to anticipate when these (or other) characters will be included in the output? I can see that they are present when a Constructed Type is used, and not so when an intrinsic type is used.

BTW, this is my first question to stackoverflow. I've found tons of valuable information here over the past couple of years. This is the first time I haven't been able to find an answer.

Comment: Also try stuff like `typeof(IComparable).ToString()`, `typeof(IComparable<>).ToString()`, `typeof(IDictionary<,>).ToString()`, `typeof(Func<,,,,>).ToString()`, and so on. And with nested types you get a `+`, for instance `typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder).ToString()`, `typeof(Dictionary<,>.KeyCollection).ToString()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Type.ToString` method uses `` `1 `` as a marker for generic types (the `1` refers to "one" generic parameter).  This:

```
 System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[System.String]
```

is the actual type name for

```
 System.Collections.Generic.Stack<System.String>
```

in C# syntax.  Note that each language can have it's own syntax.  For example, this same type, in VB, is:

```
 System.Collections.Generic.Stack(Of System.String)
```

The key difference is that `Type.ToString` is part of the CLR, and not tied to a specific language (like C#), so the syntax used for displaying generic types differs.

Answer (score 4):

Sure - the types are generic. The `` `1 `` part indicates the *number* of generic type parameters (always 1 in your case), and the `[System.String]` or `[System.Int32]` part indicates the type *argument* used for that type parameter.

So for example, if you created a `Dictionary<int, string>` you'd get:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]
```

Answer (score 1):

`` `1 `` is a number of generic type parameters.

```
System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[System.Int32]
```

Means a `Queue` with `1` type parameter which is `Int32`

Answer (score 1):

This is the CLR's notation for generic types.
The `` `1 `` means that the type has one generic parameter.

This is necessary because generic types can be overloaded – there are 8 types with the name `System.Action`.

Answer (score 0):

The CLR sometimes uses special/reserved characters behind the scenes, to ensure you cant create a class/declaration with the same name as an auto-generated one.

What you're seeing here is what a generated generic type *really* looks like, behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain what is going on here?

The `` `1[System.String] `` means that the type has one type parameters, which is `System.String` in this case.

Comment: The split thing may fail on types nested inside generic types. For example with `var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>(); var typeStr = dict.Keys.GetType().ToString();`, the string will be ``System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]`` and then it is too naïve to Split on the backtick.

Comment: @Jeppe: I understand. I removed the part about splitting on the backtick.